# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^xf(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\frac{1}{3+\cos\:x}$. We need to evaluate $\lim _{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot\int_0^xf(t)dt$.

Here is what I tried:

$ω=\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot\int_0^xf(t)dt$

I tried to use MVT, for a point $c_k\in[k,k+1]$ such that $\int_k^{k+1}f(t)dt=f(c_k)$. Therefore because $f$ is increasing on $\in[k,k+1]$ we'll obtain $f(k+1)\ge f(c_k)\ge f(k)$. Through summation it involving that:

$$\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}f(k+1)\ge\int_0^xf(t)dt\ge\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k)$$

$$\rightarrow \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot(f(1)+f(2)+\cdots)\ge ω\ge\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot(f(0)+f(1)+\cdots)$$

---

> I tried an personal method. when $x\rightarrow\infty$, $ω\rightarrow 0$. I want to know if this method is valid because it seems pretty good to tends to $0$.

**P.S:** I DON'T WANT ANOTHER METHOD, I KNOW IT TENDS TO $0$, WHAT I WANT IS TO ASK AT YELLOW BOX. WHAT IS NOT VERY CLEAR AT MY METHOD?

Comment: HINT: use L'Hospital rule.

Comment: i don't understand why you need to do all this. for a $2\pi$-periodic positive function $f,$ you have $n\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\, dx \le \int_0^{2n\pi+\epsilon} f(x) \, dx = (n+1) \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \,dx.$ now the quotient $\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x f(x)\,dx = O(1/x) $

Comment: hi @abel it is just a curiosity, I know there is any other easiest methods to prove that it tends to $0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By L'Hospital you have
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\int_0^x f(t) dt}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{2x}$$
since $f(x) \to \frac{1}{4}$ and $2x \to 0$, the limit does not exist (right and left limits are $\pm \infty$).

As for $\lim_{x \to +\infty}$, simply use the squeeze theorem using the inequality
$$\frac{1}{4} \le f(x) \le \frac{1}{2}$$
to get that the limit is $0$.

Comment: @Lucas: Either you made a mistake or the book is wrong.

Comment: $f(0) = \frac{1}{3+ \cos 0} = \frac{1}{3+1} = \frac{1}{4}$. Recall that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: use that $-1 \le \cos x \le 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: now is clear... but why the function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ if $cos(x)$ get value between $[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: @Crostul why my method doesn't work? can you ask at the yellow question ?

Comment: $f$ is not decreasing in $[k, k+1]$. Why do you say that it is decreasing? It's a periodic function: it cannot be decreasing.

Comment: okay, I will change the sign, now my method is work?

Comment: No. A periodic function is not decreasing. Your method does not make much sense for periodic functions. Moreover, Taylor expansion works only locally on the point you are expanding, so this cannot be done with $\infty$.

Comment: @Crostul ? my method show that limit tends to $0$, when $x\rightarrow\infty$, what's wrong?

Comment: @copper.hat ? what is wrong at my method?

Comment: @Lucas: There was a significant change to the question an hour ago when the limit was changed from zero to $\infty$. Big change.

Comment: @copper.hat I know that, so my method is valid?

Comment: @Lucas How should we tell you that your method is not valid? The function is not decreasing.

Comment: @Lucas: Look at Crostul's second last comment. No point in repeating.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a direct way. Clearly, $f(t) = \dfrac1{3+\cos(t)}$ is integrable on $[0,x]$. We hence have
$$\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}4 \leq \int_0^{x}\dfrac{dt}{3+\cos(t)} \leq \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}2 \implies \dfrac{x}4 \leq \int_0^{x}\dfrac{dt}{3+\cos(t)} \leq \dfrac{x}2$$
Hence, we obtain
$$\dfrac1{4x} \leq \dfrac1{x^2} \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{3+\cos(t)} \leq \dfrac1{2x}$$
Taking the limit as $x \to \infty$, we obtain
$$0 \leq \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac1{x^2} \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{3+\cos(t)} \leq 0 \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac1{x^2} \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{3+\cos(t)} = 0$$

Comment: user I know this method, I want to ask at my yellow box... is something wrong at my method?